# How can i resize css icon?

Tags: css, icons, size

Hi i want to use this icon on my homepage

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNVaMP)

```
.logo.chrome {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 210px;
  width: 210px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

But it's css and when i try to change width or height the icon shape is massed

The icon is too big want to change size to make it smaller

Is there any guide?

Want to select whole css and change size

Answer (score 1):

To edit such css shapes with different colors and dimensions, you need to try different combinations for widths, heights and margins [*proportionately*] *for all relevant classes*. And since you'll be editing css, you might actually need something like [***less***](http://lesscss.org/) for more maintainable and extendable code.

Have a look at [this](http://verekia.com/less-css/dont-read-less-css-tutorial-highly-addictive) tutorial. It is concerned with drawing css shapes and editing them. Hope it'll help

Cheers!